# X and Y Intercepts From Slopes - Python

Tags: python, calculator

I have been working on a slope calculator that also finds x and y intercepts... how do I do this in Python? Thanks!
Here is my current code:

```
def getSlope(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    slope = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
    return slope

def getYInt(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    s = getSlope(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    x = 0
    y = s*0 + yi
```

Comment: From memory I think it should be `return s * -x1 + y1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the y-intercept (b), you need to set x to one of the x values and y to one if the y values and solve:

```
y=mx+b
b=y-mx
```

The function could look like this:

```
m=getSlope(x1,y1,x2,y2)
b=y1-m*x1
return b
```

The coordinates of the point would be `(0,b)`, so you can return that instead if you want.

Answer (score 3):

For slope:

```
from __future__ import division
def getSlope((x1, y1), (x2, y2)):
    return (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
```

For y-intercept

```
def getYInt((x1, y1), (x2, y2)):
    slope = getSlope((x1, y1), (x2, y2))
    y = -x1*slope+y1
    return (0, y)
```

---

```
>>> slope((7, 3), (2, 9))
-1.2
>>> getYInt((7, 3), (2, 9))
(0, 11.4)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

the formula for a line is

```
y = m * x + c # m-->slope, c-->intercept
c = y - m * x # same formula rearranged.
```

in your `getYInt` function you only need these lines:

```
def getYInt(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    s = getSlope(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    return y1 - s * x1
```

Also, if you're on Python 2 series, be wary about integer division.

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as the other two answers.

Comment: yeah @KSFT. I think we all submitted our answers at around the same time, and as far as I'm aware, there's only one straightforward way to get the slope / intercept of a line.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

def test(did_pass):
    """  Print the result of a test.  """
    linenum = sys._getframe(1).f_lineno   # Get the caller's line number.
    if did_pass:
        msg = "Test at line {0} ok.".format(linenum)
    else:
        msg = ("Test at line {0} FAILED.".format(linenum))
    print(msg)


def slope(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

test(slope(5, 3, 4, 2) == 1.0)  # ok
test(slope(1, 2, 3, 2) == 0.0)  # ok
test(slope(1, 2, 3, 3) == 0.5)  # ok
test(slope(2, 4, 1, 2) == 2.0)  # ok

def intercept(x1, y1, x2, y2):   # y1 = mx1 + q -> q = y1 - mx1
    m = slope(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    q = y1 - m * x1
    return q

test(intercept(1, 6, 3, 12) == 3.0)  # ok
test(intercept(6, 1, 1, 6) == 7.0)   # ok
test(intercept(4, 6, 12, 8) == 5.0)  # ok
```

Comment: Don't bother about the first function it is just to check if the other two are correct. Namasté

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def find_slope(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    """
    Suppose our line is: y=mx+b.
    m is slope.
    y_deviations = y2-y1
    x_deviations = x2-x1
    m = y_deviations/x_deviations
    """
    y_deviations = y2-y1
    x_deviations = x2-x1
    
    try:
        m = y_deviations / x_deviations
        return m
    except Exception as e:
        st = f'{e.__class__.__name__} occurred.\n'
        st += f'{y2=}, {y1=}, {x2=}, {x1=}\n'
        st += f'{y2}-{y1}/{x2}-{x1} = {y2-y1}/{x2-x1}'
        return st

def find_intercept(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    """
    Suppose our line is: y=mx+b.
    m is slope.
    b is y_intercept.
    b equals to y-mx on either (x1,y1) or (x2,x2).
    So, b has the value y1-m*x1 or y2-m*x2.
    """

    try:
        m = find_slope(x1, y1, x2, y2)
        intercept = -m*x2 + y2
        return intercept,m
    except Exception as e:
        st = f'\n{e.__class__.__name__} occurred.\n'
        st += f'{type(m) = }\n'
        st += f'{type(x1) = }\n'
        st += f'{type(x2) = }\n'
        st += f'{type(y1) = }\n'
        st += f'{type(y2) = }\n'
        st += 'b = -m*x1 + y1 \n'
        st += 'or b = -m*x2 + y2'
        return st

### Driver Code ###
intercept,m = find_intercept(x1=-1, x2=1, y1=0, y2=2)
print (intercept,m)

x = np.linspace(start=-3, stop=3, num=100)
y = m*x+1
plt.plot(x, y, label=f'{m}*x+1')
plt.hlines(y=0, xmin=-5, xmax=5, colors='k', alpha=.4, ls='dashed')
plt.vlines(x=0, ymin=-5, ymax=5, colors='k', alpha=.4, ls='dashed')
plt.xlim(-5, 5)
plt.xlim(-3, 3)
plt.grid()
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(which='minor', alpha=.2, ls='-', c='gray')
x1,y1,x2,y2 = -1,0,1,2
plt.scatter(x2,y2, marker='o', c='hotpink')
plt.scatter(x1,y1, marker='o', c='hotpink')
plt.scatter(0,intercept, marker='o', c='green')
plt.legend()
```